# f# xamarin blank android project error on deploy: Can not resolve reference: FSharp.Core

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, f#

I am trying to setup a xamarin android project using f# with Visual Studio 2019, but I can't seem to get to the point where "Hello world!" would show on my device!

The template project build succeeds, and my device is successfully connected. However, attempting to deploy the project fails with **error telling me the reference to the FSharp.Core could not be resolved**. If there is anyone who knows more about this issue, or can speculate to what is going on and what might be done to solve it, any help would be much appreciated.

Upon creating a blank android application I stumbled on the error explained in [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/665737/package-installation-error-when-creating-new-blank.html):

`Xamarin.Android.FSharp.ResourceProvider` seemed to be missing, and the FSharp.Core not referenced. I solved this problem by installing both via Nuget. However, looking at my intellisense and console errors, the FSharp.Core was still not properly loaded.

After reading [this article](https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html), I managed to make intellisense happy and the build succeed by editing the fsproj files reference to the FSharp.Core from "Include" to "Update".

```
<PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="4.7.0" />
```

However, this time I get a reference error when attempting to deploy the project to my android device.

```
XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `FSharp.Core`, referenced by `Xamarin.Android.FSharp.ResourceProvider.Runtime`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `FSharp.Core`, or remove the reference to `Xamarin.Android.FSharp.ResourceProvider.Runtime`.

XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `FSharp.Core`, referenced by `Playground`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `FSharp.Core`, or remove the reference to `Playground`.
```

(`Playground` is the projects name)

I am deploying to a relatively old device (android 4.3, api level 18), but looking at the errors it does not seem related to the failure. I must be missing something simple like a build or reference setting.

Comment: It might be worth adding a reference (via References / Framework) rather than the Nuget Package, despite what the F# core page says.  This Microsoft page mentions F# Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/internals/available-assemblies

Comment: @GregHNZ
Thanks for your suggestion!

The FSharp.Core did not seem to be listed in the available framework references.
Copying the dll I got from the nuget package to that folder manually seems to have done the trick though, even though I am still referencing the nuget package.
I have also added the `<Private>true</Private>` to the reference in my fsproj file to make sure the dll is included in the build.

There must be a more proper way to set this up, but it seems to work for now!
Thanks again for your input.

Comment: Seems I only pushed the error one step further along the road.
The deploy succeeds, but now the FSharp.Core.dll cannot be found when running the application.

`The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly (/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/Playground.Playground/files/.__override__/).`

Comment: For what it's worth (which is probably 'not much') the blank Android Mobile F# app worked first time in *VS2017*.  I couldn't even create the project without an error in VS2019.

Answer (score 0):

> I managed to make intellisense happy and the build succeed by editing the fsproj files reference to the FSharp.Core from "Include" to "Update".

No, you should *adding* instead of *editing*, like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="FSharp.Core" Version="4.7.0" />
<PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="4.7.0" />
```

This is a workaround for VSMac bug https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/pull/5137